# issue with mysqldump and foreign key

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database on linux that I want to export to mysql running under Windows.
I have made a dump of the mysql database.
When I want to import it in the empty schema in Windows, I am getting :

> ERROR 1215(HY000)at line 2685  : cannot add foreign ley constraint.

I don't understand why.
Any advice?
Thank you.

UPDATE :

From Linux 18.04 - **Mysql 5.7.28**   to   Linux 14.04 - **Mysql 5.5.54**
`mysql -u root myDB<myDB.sql`
-> **OK** import successful

From Linux 18.04 - **Mysql 5.7.28**   to   Windows 10 - **Mysql 5.7.21**
`mysql -u root myDB<myDB.sql`

or

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
source myDB.sql;
```

-> **KO**  :  import failed

> ERROR 1215(HY000)at line 2685 : cannot add foreign key constraint.
>   ERROR 1146 (42S02) table xxx doesn't exist

Comment: Make sure you dump the tables that are referenced before the tables that reference them. `mysqldump` won't put them in the correct order automatically.

Comment: Actually, according to the question I just linked to, it's supposed to turn off FK checks so this shouldn't be a problem. I'm not sure why you're getting that error unless you're using a really old version of mysqldump.

Comment: I have updated my post with more details, maybe it will help.

Comment: I think turning off FK checks doesn't mean you can reference a table that doesn't exist when you're creating the FK. You need to put the tables in the correct order.

Comment: the import works well in a linux environment though, that's what I don't understand.

Comment: I suspect you were importing into a database that already has the tables, and it was simply overwriting them. But if you try to import into an empty database, the referenced tables don't exist.